# Move the all relation old node to new node

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using neo4j. I want to move the all relations old node to new node. [image]
In this image, I mentioned old node and new node in yellow color.incase old node can have 1,2 or 3 relations. Whatever relationships there are it should all be taken to the new node

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/#merge-nodes). The procedure has several options, and you should read the documentation to decide how you want to "merge" the 2 nodes.